# Sinal de + antes da função em JQuery? o que significa?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Vou terminar um sistema iniciado por outro colega que foi desligado da empresa e estou na dúvida quanto ao uso de `+` antes de iniciar a função, e gostaria de saber qual o impacto dessa atribuição, segue exemplo:

```
+function ($) {

//funções dentro do arquivo .js
//e termina dessa forma

}(jQuery);
```

Estou acostumado a trabalhar de duas maneiras;

1. `$(function ($) {...})`
2. `$(document).ready( function() {...})`

Comment: Eu já vi isso respondi aqui.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `+` na frente da função serve para executá-la imediatamente [IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossario/IIFE). Caso não exista este operador ou qualquer outra forma de indicar que a função será executada imediatamente a declaração não será considerada como uma expressão pelo `parser` do navegador.

No caso do seu exemplo você está executando a função logo após defini-la e passa como parâmetro a variável `JQuery`. No caso do seu primeiro exemplo, pode-se utilizar outras sintaxes também, como por exemplo a seguinte:

```
(function ($) {

//funções dentro do arquivo .js
//e termina dessa forma

})(jQuery);
```

Você pode utilizar qualquer operador unário para ter o mesmo resultado:

```
!function(){ /* implementação */ }();
~function(){ /* implementação */ }();
-function(){ /* implementação */ }();
+function(){ /* implementação */ }();
```

Comment: O `-` também pode ser utlizado? aí de forma inversa?

Comment: @WagnerFernandoMomesso adicionei a resposta para isso na pergunta